# div not floating side by side

Tags: html, css, layout

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="header">Transport</div>
        <div id="image">
            <img src="../images/img1.jpg" style="width:300px;height:300px"/>
        </div>
        <div id="right_content">large amount of text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the above the css used is:

```
#content {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#outer {
    border: 1px solid;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
}

#header {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #006A4D;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    font: normal 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 18px;
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
}

#right_content {
    border: 1px solid;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    background-color: orange;
    font: normal 12px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 18px;
}

#image {
    border: 1px solid;
    min-width: 300px;
    min-height: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Both the inner divs are `float:left`. But the output comes as one div below the other. How can I get them to appear side by side?

Comment: it should be side by side, unless your window is too small to fit them both side by side. In which case you will have to make the outer two div a fixed width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave `#image` and `#outer` a width and `#right_content` a negative margin to account for the `#image`'s space.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stealthyninja/Hn2Et/

Answer (score 5):

Works fine for me at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/zv4zG/

The thing to keep in mind is that if you do not specify widths for the floated elements, and they grow in size in order to accommodate their contents, they may reach a size (*when added*) that exceeds their container width. At that point they will break and one will go below the other.

So, you have to ensure that their added widths (*and horizontal paddings and margins*) will never exceed their containers width.

Comment: I tried it. When I added a large amount of text, the divs became one below the other

Comment: @user, then you made some error.. if you give fixed widths to the inner elements that do not exceed their parents, there is no way they will break..

Answer (score 4):

the outer div has a 100% width, witch tells the browser to ocupy all the available width, that's why the second div drops beneath.

The solution is simple, make sure both divs have enough width to be able to be side by side.

Comment: Yep, just specify a literal width

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to float the `#right_content`, just add a left margin wide enough to accommodate the image and drop the `overflow`:

```
#right_content{
    border: 1px solid;
    min-height: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 322px;
    background-color: orange;
    font: normal 12px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8m3LS/

Answer (score 1):

DIVs are block-level elements, meaning that they will stack vertically by default. In order to make them appear side-by-side, you will also need to set `display: inline;` in your CSS.

**UPDATE**

I just created this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncdSr/) and it looks like your layout is fine... not sure what the issue is. Could it be browser specific?

Comment: That does not make any difference. It still appears one below the other

Answer (score 0):

As we give width to one of the div, it leaves the extra space for next div, but make sure the width of both divs do not exceeds the browser's width, otherwise the second div will move below the first div. this css worked for me:

```css
#left{
display:inline;
width:50%;
float:left;
}
#right{
float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
left div
</div>
<div id="right">
right div
</div>
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your Answer, you should explain *how* it is that your code worked and theirs did not.  Please include links to any research you performed that proved to be useful (and pertinent).  Also, I recommend setting the `background-color` for each div to something like `yellow` for 'a' and `blue` for 'b' - this will more readily indicate where the boundaries of the `div`'s are in contrast to each other and the main `body` of the page.